# Select option in optgroup with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select `option` in `optgroup` automatically when a select a user in the select list.

Consider the select code

```html
<select name="city">
  <optgroup label="Zone 1">
    <option value="1"> City 1</option>
    <option value="2"> City 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Zone 2">
    <option value="3"> City 1</option>
    <option value="4"> City 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I have the user table and update action. When a click on the update button I show the update user modal and set the user information on it. The city option is not selected atomically.

```js
$(".update-user").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).data("json");
  var $updateUserModal = $('#update-user-modal');

  for (key in data) {
    $updateUserModal
    .find('[name="' + key + '"]')
    .val(data[key]);
  }
});
```

When the modal is shown the city is not selected

Comment: what exactrly are you trying to achieve with `.find('[name="' + key + '"]')`? there aren't any attributes other than `name="city"` in your example. so what are you looking for?

Comment: I want to set the from value through it

Comment: The city is not selected. But if the select has not option the code work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it works for you.

```
$(".update-user").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).data("json");
  var $updateUserModal = $('#update-user-modal');

  for (key in data) {
    $updateUserModal.find('[name="' + key + '"]').val(data[key]);
  }

  // Set the selected option in the city select element
  $updateUserModal.find('[name="city"]').val(data["city"]);
});
```

Comment: Not work for me!